# box-shadow:inset for react-native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to implement box inner shadow similar to what you can achieve using box-shadow:inset in CSS. I tried the following, but I can't get it the shadow more prominent and darker. https://rnplay.org/apps/EHvL4g

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
    box: {
    margin: 20,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 1,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowRadius: 10,
    shadowOpacity: 1,
    },
});
```

Answer (score 15):

Increase the borderWidth.

```css
box: {
  margin: 10,
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  borderColor: 'white',
  borderWidth: 30,
  overflow: 'hidden',
  shadowColor: 'black',
  shadowRadius: 10,
  shadowOpacity: 1,
}
```

[image]