# React Native Inset Shadow Effect

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

[image: Figma example]

I have a Figma example of a bottom navigation tab bar (image above). It includes two buttons that are displayed with a `focused` effect. As you can see, when the button is pushed (focused on) it has an inset shadow (which seems to be impossible to achieve at this point in RN), and the other one has an elevation effect. Assume that they would switch when another button becomes under-focused.

The problem lies in implementing the inset shadow for me. I have applied several approaches to this problem but couldn't find an optimal solution. As [some of the examples](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2255) show that there is a possibility of reaching the inset shadow for a box (rectangular); I find it impossible to achieve the same result for the circular button.

The ways that I have tried:

1. Trying to add a normal shadow (elevation effect). That works for an `elevated` button, but can't be applied to the `focused` one. (i used some shadow generator like [this one by Ether](https://ethercreative.github.io/react-native-shadow-generator/))
2. Trying `react-native-svg` which would allow us to build a custom XML/CSS file with all properties (except `inset`, as it is not supported?)
3. Trying [Expo Linear Gradient](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/linear-gradient/). I have tried to go from [x:0,y:1] to [x:1,y:0] - diagonal way with colors - [black (10%), grey(40%), light grey (40%), white (10%)]. It does look almost right, but still it is not radial as i expected it to be.
4. Trying conditional rendering. I know it is a bad experience rendering the image based on condition, but I have tried to create two images in GIMP (one with focused effect and one without), but I honestly couldn't do it with circular images...

If anybody can propose any good solution or pinch me in the right direction, I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Does that example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/soulwire/pen/bKens) look similar to what you want?

Comment: This answer may help you: [see answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084120/box-shadowinset-for-react-native)

Comment: @YanaTrifonova this includes `inset` css which is not supported.

Comment: @AliSafari this doesn't include 2-color shadow as shown on Sigma image above (diagonal effect from black to white shadow)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this library [react-native-neomorph-shadows](https://github.com/tokkozhin/react-native-neomorph-shadows)
[image]
something like this

```js
import { Neomorph } from 'react-native-neomorph-shadows';

...

<Neomorph
  inner // <- enable shadow inside of neomorph
  swapShadows // <- change zIndex of each shadow color
  style={{
    shadowRadius: 10,
    borderRadius: 75,
    backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
  }}
>
</Neomorph>
```

##### UPDATE: expo support

as @denistepp comment This library is not working with expo 
the [docs](https://github.com/tokkozhin/react-native-neomorph-shadows#installation) say

> IMPORTANT: this library, `starting from v1.0.0, no longer supports expo` because React Native Art library was recently deprecated from expo.

#### but you still have a chance with version min v1.0.0

i create this [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/QMelLhmmp?platform=ios) with this dependencies

```js
"react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
"react-native-neomorph-shadows": "0.0.8"
```

see can find version v0.0.8 docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-neomorph-shadows/v/0.0.8)

##### The result

[image]

##### full code work with expo last version v42

```
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { ShadowBox, NeomorphBox } from 'react-native-neomorph-shadows';

export default function App() {

    return (
      <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection : "row",
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        backgroundColor: '#fcfcfc',
      }}>
        
        <ShadowBox
          inner
          useSvg
          style={{
            shadowOffset: {width: 3, height: 3}, 
            shadowOpacity: .8,
            shadowColor: "#ddd",
            shadowRadius: 3,
            borderRadius: 35,
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            width: 70,
            height: 70,
          }}>
        </ShadowBox>

        <ShadowBox
          useSvg
          style={{
            shadowOffset: {width: 4, height: 4}, 
            shadowOpacity: .8,
            shadowColor: "#e6e6e6",
            shadowRadius: 3,
            borderRadius: 35,
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            width: 70,
            height: 70,
          }}>
        </ShadowBox>
      </View>
    );
  
}
```

Comment: This library is not working with expo anymore nor react-native cli. The known issue there is the deprecation of `ReactNativeART`. Unless they switch to `react-native-svg`, this is not a solution.

Comment: i update my answer with example support expo

Comment: had some problems with types (as I was using TS), but it worked as a charm on 0.0.8! Thank you very much!

Comment: library is outdated at this point of time